# Lie algebras of same dimension are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

I just began studying Lie algebras and I'm trying to prove that two Lie algebras $\frak g$ and $\frak h$ are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension.

If they're isomorphic, then proving that they have the same dimension goes just like for vector spaces, I guess.

Now, if $\{g_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $\{h_i\}_{i \in I}$ are bases for $\frak g$ and $\frak h$, we can define a linear map $T\colon {\frak g}\to {\frak h}$ by $Tg_i = h_i$, for all $i \in I$, and extending. But then we should check that $T$ also preserves commutators, so $T$ will be a morphism of Lie algebras.

If $[g_i,g_j] = \sum_k c_{ij}^kg_k$ and $[h_i,h_j]= \sum_k d_{ij}^kh_k$, writing $x=  \sum_i a_i g_i$ and $y = \sum_j b_jg_j$, I got: $$ T[x,y] = \sum_{i,j,k}a_ib_jc_{ij}^k h_k, \qquad [Tx,Ty] = \sum_{i,j,k} a_ib_j d_{ij}^k h_k. $$How can I prove that $c_{ij}^k = d_{ij}^k$? I guess I should use Jacobi's identity, but I'm not sure of how exactly doing this. Help?

Comment: I think you can prove two abelian lie algebras of same dimension are isomorphic.

Comment: Yes, definitely. This post is very old and the question was naive. I wasn't aware that Lie algebras form a completely different category, so the notion of isomorphism is not the same as one for vector spaces. Preserving the Lie bracket does not follow from linearity at all.

Comment: In fact, 2015 me proved without realizing that two Lie algebras are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension *and* have bases for which the structure constants are the same. Of course, this characterization might not be very useful in practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not true. Take  the set of all $6\times6$ matrices with usual bracket operation $[A,B]=AB-BA$. This is 36-dimensional Lie algebra.

Now look at upper triangular matrices of size $9\times 9$, under the 'same' operation. This is of dimension $9\times8/2=36$. They are not isomorphic. (Second one is solvable, whereas the first is not). Of course it is much easier to give example with one of them  with trivial Lie algebra structure.

Comment: Oh boy. Thanks for the quick answer, I got it.

Comment: There are infinitely many such examples; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number.

Comment: Thanks lhf for pointing out the method for generating more examples.

Answer (score 2):

The minimal counterexample is of dimension $2$. Every $2$-dimensional Lie algebra over a field $K$ is either isomorphic to the abelian Lie algebra $K^2$, or to the solvable, non-abelian Lie algebra $\mathbb{r}_2(K)$, with basis $(x,y)$ and Lie bracket $[x,y]=x$. These two Lie algebras cannot be isomorphic for various reasons. The most obvious property is that $K^2$ has zero brackets, and $\mathbb{r}_2(K)$ has not. Another invariant is that $\dim Der(K^2))=4$ whereas $\dim Der(\mathbb{r}_2(K))=2$ for the derivation algebras.
A third argument is that $L=\mathbb{r}_2(K)$ is not nilpotent. Indeed $[L,[L,L]]=[L,L]$ stabilizes. Of course, $K^2$ is nilpotent.